# how to fix "Missing mandatory keyword argument 'size' in function call" pylint(missing-kwoa) E1125

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I want to pass an array, int to a function of different file and I want to return int(1 to 9)
I have simplified it but it is still showing error E1125

```
# in basic.py
 import neural_network as nu
 import numpy as np
 import math


import neural_network as nu

def AI_connector(): 
            Inputv = np.zeros((9), dtype=float)  # input array
            size=9
            return nu.connector(Inputv,size)

# in neural_network.py

import numpy as np
import math 
import random 

Inputv = np.zeros((9), dtype=float)  #input array


def connector(myList=[], *args,size):
    Inputv = np.zeros((size), dtype=float)  #input array
    Inputv=myList
    return 0
```

Comment: i have changed 
def connector(myList=[], size,*args):
to 
def connector(myList=[],*args,size,):
   error came
unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Sorry, I missed the default argument for `myList`. You cannot have a a parameter without default parameter after one with one, so either give `size` a default as well or remove the one from `myList`. Please don't change the code in your question (instead edit in some additional text). Now the error message in the question doesn't match the code anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```py
def connector(myList=[], *args,size):
```

should be

```py
def connector(size, myList=[], *args):
```

You always put the default arguments first, then the non-default ones. You put `*args` and `**kwargs` in the end.